# active admin nested resources form generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am able to generate the required layout for nested attribute form like the below image:

[image: form layout I want]

The code for nested form:

```
f.inputs 'Line Item/s' do
    f.has_many :payment_line_items, heading: false do |form|
      table do
        tr do
          th 'Description'
          th 'Qty'
          th 'Unit Price'
          th 'Amount'
        end
        tr do
          td {form.input :description, label: false}
          td {form.input :quantity, label: false}
          td {form.input :unit_price, label: false}
          td {form.input :amount, label: false}
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

When I click on 'add new payment line Item button' I get something like this image:

[image: after adding the line item]

I just want to duplicate the whole table or just the tr with the form part when I click on 'add new payment line Item' button. How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue in one of my activeadmin projects. The `fieldset` element uses `li` elements that you can style. So check the class the form is using, and than add something like this to the end of `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss`. Here I assume the css class on the surrounding form is `line_items`. The trick is the `inline-block` property on the `li` element, you may have to fiddle with the css properties though.

```css
form.line_items fieldset.has_many_fields ol > li > label { display: none; }
form.line_items fieldset.has_many_fields:first-child ol > li > label { display: block; }
form.line_items fieldset.has_many_fields ol > li { display: inline-block; padding: 5px; width: 18%; float:left;}
form.line_items fieldset.has_many_fields ol > li.has_many_delete { margin-top:20px; margin-left: -36px;}
form.line_items fieldset.has_many_fields ol > li > label { width: auto; padding-right: 10px;}
form.line_items fieldset.has_many_fields ol > li > div > label.label { width: auto; padding-right: 10px;}
form.line_items fieldset.has_many_fields ol > li > a.has_many_remove { margin-top:20px; }
form.line_items fieldset.has_many_fields ol > li > p.inline-errors { margin: 0.3em 0 0 0; }
```

This would work but you will have to rewrite the form to:

```
  f.inputs 'Line Item/s' do
    f.has_many :payment_line_items, heading: false do |form|
      form.input :description, label: false
      form.input :quantity, label: false
      form.input :unit_price, label: false
      form.input :amount, label: false                    
    end
  end
```

If you want the user to be able to destroy line items you will have to set up your assocations and the permit_params for it like so:

In your model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items, :allow_destroy => true
```

And in the activeadmin register block:

```
permit_params \
  :line_items_attributes => [:id, :description, :quantity, :unit_price, :amount, :_destroy]
```

Good luck!

Comment: I am not able to set the common heading as shown in the image above, like descritption, quantity, amount, unit_price

Comment: Hi Bipin, my error I think. The label property on the form inputs should be omitted. And then the first 2 css rules make it so that only the first labels are retained.